# Click event for 3rd party custom elements without removing existing event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, webapi, custom-element

I have included a third party custom tag, and loading one external js file, the js file is appending few more elements to it. I tried to bind a click event for the element. But not working.

```
<!-- 3rd party custom element -->
<pin-location></pin-location>
```

After loading external js file, 3rd party plugin js file is appending few more elements like below

```
<each-pin><p>Pin1</p></each-pin>
<each-pin><p>Pin2</p></each-pin>
```

when i click on the paragraph i want send some analytics without removing existing event handlers from the paragraph.

I have tried below

```
customElements.get('pin-location', class extends HTMLElement {
            connectedCallback() {
                alert("hi");
                this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
                this.shadowRoot.firstElementChild.onclick = e => alert("Inner target: " + e.target.tagName);
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach you need. For demo purposes I've simulated the custom elements you've mentioned, the relevant part for you is the last IIFE.

```js
customElements.define('pin-location', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }
});

customElements.define('each-pin', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = 'Paragraph here';
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(p);
  }
});

// This simulates the third party JS you mentioned
(function() {
  const eachPin = document.createElement('each-pin');
  document.querySelector('pin-location').shadowRoot.appendChild(eachPin);
}());

// here's how you attach an additional click listener to the paragraph
(function() {
  const pinLocations = document.querySelectorAll('pin-location');
  for (const pinLocation of pinLocations) {
    const allPins = pinLocation.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('each-pin');
    for (const eachPin of allPins) {
      eachPin.shadowRoot.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log(e.target);
      })
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<pin-location></pin-location>
```

Please note that as of now, you cannot access *closed* shadow roots this way. This is about to change with the introduction of [declarative shadow DOM](https://web.dev/declarative-shadow-dom/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
customElements.get('pin-location', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
     alert("hi");
     this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
     this.shadowRoot.firstElementChild.onclick = e => alert("Inner target: " + e.target.tagName);
  }
 });
```

Your code (above) uses `customElements.get()`; which **checks** if a Custom Element `pin-location` **is defined**, it returns the definition, not the DOM element.
That second parameter (class) does nothing

You can `.define` a Custom Element with:

```html
<each-pin id=ONE   ></each-pin>
<each-pin id=TWO   ></each-pin>
<each-pin id=THREE ></each-pin>

<script>
  customElements.define('each-pin', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      p.textContent = 'Paragraph here';
      p.onclick = (evt) => alert("You clicked: " + this.id);

      super() // sets and returns this-scope
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets and returns this.shadowRoot 
        .append(p); // no need for appendChild 
    }
    // addListener( type, func) { ... }
  });
</script>
```

- Keep Components and behaviour together; if you add listeners from other code then add least do it with a `addListener` method on the Component, so the Component can track and clean up listeners.
- You want to use the `constructor` because the `connectedCallback` *can* run multiple times (when the element is moved around in the DOM)
- It is your Component, you are in charge, so it is perfectly valid to use the 'oldskool' **inline** `onclick` event handler instead of `addEventListener`
- Default events like `click` bubble; but do read all of the MDN documentation when sending (Custom)Events:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent